# I'm level 20: what now?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I have a level 20 warrior.  I've read the [wiki's Game Objectives section](http://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/game-objectives), which lists

- Gravestones
- Achievements
- Class Quests & Fame Ranks
- Fame Earning
- Guilds

I'd like to hunt big monsters or gods, since it's the only "mini-quest"/objective that I can perform (seems a bit silly to me, by the way).  But even if I have a level 20 character, one of these fellas will kill me with a simple shot.  And if it doesn't, the swarm around them will.

How can I continue to improve my character's performances even after I reached the level cap ?  I can't find any good stuff (armor, weapon, spell), because I can't kill the big monsters that will drop it...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Group up. The game is all about ad-hoc parties. Just take a look at the minimap (you can zoom out with your mouse wheel) and find a big cluster of players. Press "teleport" and you'll most likely end up smack in the middle of a fight.

You'll propably want to find a place with lesser gods (big monsters that take lots of hits, but aren't in your mini-quests). Killing them in a group of even a few people, if there's even one healer around, shouldn't be too difficult, but I'd still advise you to be careful.

Once you're geared up so that you can take more than one hit from the big gods (but don't get too cocky, they'll still hit hard), try to find or gather up a group to kill one of the big baddies that Onyx keeps mentioning. They'll take a lot of hits and practically require a group of at least a dozen players, with exeption of few of the weaker ones.

And even though you've hit the level cap, you can still progress. Gear is the easiest way to get more powerful, but what all players really want to gather are stats raising potions. These drop rarely and only from the toughest of monsters. They will permanently increase any of your stats, thus making you a bit more capable at fighting bigger monsters and finding more. You'll find them most reliably dropped by (late game, ie. not Pirate Cave) dungeon bosses.

tl;dr Don't solo, teleport to a group, get gear and stats potions.

Comment: Excellent; thanks for the advice !  When you talk about grouping up: you mean "locking" players on the bottom right of the screen andn stick to them ?

Comment: That's not needed. I'm just talking about generally being in the same area. Locking helps to keep a spesific group together, but you rarely need to be in a spesific group. As long as you got a bunch of other level 20s around you and tought monsters for them to kill, you should be alright. Also, keep an eye out for the chat. Players often request people to gather up to kill a paticulary tough monster. You can join them by simply typing "/teleport [player name]" to the chat.

Answer (score 9):

One thing a lot of newer players neglect is the dungeons.

Dungeons like the Undead Lair are not particularly difficult once you learn the ins and outs of them, but can be very rewarding. I regularly solo the Undead Lair with newly created level 20 characters when I need to rebuild my gear collection.
http://forums.wildshadow.com/wiki/realm-mad-god/undead-lair

The final boss usually drops a wisdom pot or something, but can drop the Doom Bow which is one of the most valuable items in the game.

Comment: +1: And if you play range, particularly priest or necro, a fresh level 20 can easily solo sprite. The combination of heal and the range to avoid being shot/chased by Limon gives these classes an easy mode. I personally avoid soloing Undead Lair until I've quaffed a couple def pots because of those Quiet shots from Septavius (warning: the other shots from him do not get reduced with def).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest different tactics for farming for different classes.

First off, if you can gather the real life player skill to go after red demons, you can get T9 armor out of their chests. If you cant, make a rogue and dive those chest carefully until you can get 1. Its worth the wait for your squish characters. T8 drops from all the "godland" monsters.

When fighting godland monsters and your going to tp in: PUT ON HP RING, the def ring is 1 for 1 reduction, so if your takin 90 damage hits, and get hit 2-7 times on a burst, your talking major damage. A T3 hp ring is easy to get and will allow you greater chances when TP into a fight (which is always a fight), as well as not worth enough to care if you lose.

All the godland monsters will drop T4 rings. patience and you will get some.

If you cant deal with godlands, go to the 3rd road. Yes each road goes all the way around the world in 3 levels. On that road, the stone golems that spawn gnomes and the lizards that spawn archers spawn snake pit dungeons. You can make it through these and get speed potions and T9 weapons rarely. you can trade speed potions up for other potions until your strong enough to WOOP DAT MOB.

For Wizards(highest DPS and probly the easyest to farm with, 75 att/dex max) running the world on mid lands (road 2) you can search the dark dark grass for coil snakes and get into "forbidden jungles" for a strong UT staff. Never use the UT robe because it has no defense and no attack bonus. Necromancers may also like to pick up a skull here, the AOE on it is much larger than others, and you can heal well if you can somehow, manage to target the right half of your screen where the monsters are (yeah its that big and somehow ppl miss....)

Some classes just get the bad end of the stick. Ninjas are awesome with T2 shurikens to get soulbound damage in on most gods in godlands and a T3 is a for sure SB damage. The sad part is, they have poor bad stats overall for what they are good at. You are forced to use a pet with a decent amount of magic heal ability to make use of the ninja, and heal also because the ninja has one of the worst vitality stats in the game. Also they take the most player skill. You have to hit with your shurikens and not miss, and also while holding your special down, even for a tap most the time, your gonna go hyper speed and probly run into a shotgun and die on your first ninja or two.

If you want to level your pet and realize, your gonna die all the time with 1 character slot, its a good idea to unlock mystic. with no gear other than your orb, you can hop in any populated world and pick off contructs in god lands. you will instantly see how the mass confusion and people dying left and right stop. people turn this into a fame trains. you can aquire much fame in short time with a group of 20 ppl dedicated to running laps around the godlands. take off your weapon, dont shoot, when you want to RIP, type /tutorial in town and warp to tutorial land. shoot the walls that shoot out green blobs for a few minutes and kill yourself at 250 fame. you will get multiple bonuses. 3 levels of accuracy at 99-100%, friend of the cube for not killing any cubes. if you kill a mystic at 250 fame (1-3 hours tops), you will end up with 500+ fame.

Almost all melee is gonna get you killed until you know what your doing. You must be willing to eat all the defense potions you can. trade for them to max your defense first, and geared up to a rediculous level. Some classes like assassin can solo by throwing grenades over walls, like in snake pit, or in godlands while inside a castle. if you have patience you will get drops.

Castles are a great place for any class to be in godlands. you can pull gods 1 at a time and deal with them at your own pace. you can heal up between fights. if you have a friend its even better. you can hold your spot on an empty world and the gods will always be outside fresh for you two. you can TP into each other and bank/heal/get pots and have no problem doing it agian.

archers can be great for snake pits, but thats about it until you get a DOOM BOW. your range sucks in godlands and the normal weapon spread shit sucks even worse. its viable, but not your best starting off farming class IMO.

any class with 8.6 range weapons can off screen the limon sprite god. go in the sprite worlds with a def ring on and a vit ring in your inventory. you can shoot him from off the screen during his white wall attack, by standing in between the waves (not in the middle next to him, or next to him and just dodge). eventually he will flip out and summon monsters, so use your special there, then back away and heal up until he puts out another web wall. play with your music and shot sound off but sound affects on, you will hear yourself hit him. 3-4 rounds with a T8 weapon on a fresh level 20. eventually you will get strong enough to do it in 1 round of his white wall BS. Sprite wands are good for sorc-priest or pet feed. they also drop from green sprites rarely.

Answer (score 1):

Team up with the other NEW lvl 20 players.

I don't agree teaming up with almost maxed (or maxed) players because you don't get soulbound damage.

Most good items and stat potions are dropped from soulbound loot. After getting some better stats, join a better group to take on the BIG guys.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you start by farming with a small sized group of level 15s-20s. Depending on your class, you should go for different types of gods.

Anyone can kill a medusa. Circle around her but not to fast unless you WANT to be hit by her grenade. She has the most damage in the game but for me she id dead easy alone.

For a wand or staff class (technically any class with lots of range for the weapon attack), you can go for a LOT of different gods. Ghost Gods are easy as long as you don't get hit by them a lot.

However, no matter what class you are, WATCH OUT FOR THE LEVIATHAN. It may not have the strongest attack, but it shoots the most and has the strangest pattern of them all. Take time to notice its patterns and when dodging, move back at the same time.

Know when it's time to nexus. For a short range or medium range class, go for beholders, white demons, and ent gods. They are fairly easy as long as you know their attack problems. Get a good amount of defense when charging at a ghost god though.

Every once in a while, you will get a pot or a egg. You can drink the pot and hatch the egg, but if you want you can sell them. When I'm a low level class, I stay out of the castles of Oryx. I trade more often for better gear and stat potions. Try not to fight swarms of gods. If you see one that you can't defeat, nexus.

What I do is I stay in nexus and i say "Please donate" most of the time some one will not give you anything but some times people will throw T9 ot higher out so you have to very good reflexes in order to get the good stuff also people do a thing called  "drop party" its where a bunch of people get together and throw out there inventory just for the fun of it also to see every body fight over the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Getting friends to help you in battle is very helpful for fighting harder monsters but if you want to improve your character you should max your stats with stat potions

Answer (score 0):

you can keep killing gods and monsters so they will drop T7+ items, with them you will be stronger

Comment: i am a 20 warrior too, but i have more than700 hp and 21 defense so i can take up a lot of hits of the gods, keep playing, you will be addicted.

Answer (score -1):

Fight Oryx to get more fame and stuff like that.